# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':games_services:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-play-games

I'm using [games_services](https://github.com/Abedalkareem/games_services) and it was working ok before updating Flutter to latest version.

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':games_services:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (21).

  Consider using JVM Toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
  Learn more about JVM-target validation: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation
```

build.gradles:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

---

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

`games_services: ^4.0.1`

> Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4123], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 3.19.2 on channel stable at C:\flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision 7482962148 (10 days ago), 2024-02-27 16:51:22 -0500
> • Engine revision 04817c99c9
> • Dart version 3.3.0
> • DevTools version 2.31.1